# AppFabric 1.1 Security Between the Connection of Cache Host-Cluster

Tags: caching, appfabric, distributed-caching, appfabric-cache

I was wondering how can I disable the secure connection between cache host and cluster. I am using XML based config and I couldn't find any source for this. In default it is secure but it is not important for me so I want to disable it. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely certain about what you mean, but security configuration server side can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921012%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) and client side [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790816%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).